# Proof of an elementary property of Projection Operators

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm asked to show the following:

Let $X$ be a linear space, and let $P : X \rightarrow X$ be a projection operator. Restricted to the linear space $range(P)$, the projection $P$ is the identity operator, that is, $Px = x$ for all
$x \in range(P)$.

If anyone could offer a hint for how to show this. I'm rusty with linear algebra so don't really know what I'm supposed to bring in outside of what's specified in the lemma/definition of projection. What is so special about the range of P that would make this so?

Comment: $P^2=P$ is among the properties of a projection operator.

Comment: I understand that's the definition but I don't understand how to use this with the range of P (range(P) is not equal to P right?)

Comment: If $x\in\operatorname{range}(P)$ then $x=P(y)$ for some $y$; then $P(x)=P(P(y))=\ldots$

Comment: If this is homework, please say so.

Comment: $Px=x$ is the definition of the projection operator. We can't prove the definition. Based on this definition, we can prove a lot of other properties.

Comment: Please help me clarify - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column_space is the incorrect meaning of range? @Shiyu the definition I'm given doesn't include this property.

Comment: The range of an operator $P\colon X\rightarrow Y$ is simply the set $\{y\in Y\mid \exists x\in X \mbox{ s.t }P(x)=y\}$, sometimes called the image.

Comment: Then I was being foolish and misunderstood - thanks everyone. Also: How often is Column Space referred to as the Range?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: projection operators satisfy the property $P^2=P$ (by definition).

If $x\in\operatorname{range}(P)$, then $x=P(y)$, so $P(x)=P(P(y))=\ldots$

Comment: Thank you. I misunderstood the the definition of 'range'.

Comment: Can't get it. Still, it is $P(x)=y$.

Comment: @AnikBhowmick $P(x)=P(P(y))=P^2(y)=P(y)=x$.